# manipulating divs with media queries

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
<div class="col-lg-6"><img src=""></img></div>

<div class="col-lg-6"><img src=""></img></div>
<div class="col-lg-6">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH</div>
<div class="col-lg-6"><img src=""></img></div>
```

However, when my screen resizes to mobile I need the 2nd elements picture to still display underneath the text instead of on top.

Is this possible with any built-in Twitter Bootstrap Classes? Or some media query manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

you can use these classes. to hide and show the element according to the device

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

also you can use `col-xs-` classes

**eg:** `<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12"><img src=""></img></div>`

Comment: using col-xs- wont move an element thats above to below when resizing to mobile width